# Multiple dataprovider for itemrender in DataGrid ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

I have a DataGrid. I'm using combobox in Grid as ItemRender. I want to set dataprovider for item in each row which using combobox. Each row at item which using combobox have different dataprovider. I'm using Flex 3.

Answer (score 0):

The ComboBox dataProviders for each row must be embedded in the dataProvider for the whole Grid, and you can retrieve them selectively in the itemRenderer.